# Square wave based on falling edge of alternative pulse of upcoming RPM square wave

Tags: arduino-uno, programming

In my recent project, I have RPM Square wave from vehicle. Now, based on that I want square wave based on falling edge but only alternative pulse of RPM square wave.

I think below image clear more properly.

[image: Pulse]

Upper yellowish square wave which I need. And below pinkish square wave is RPM square wave.

I made a code for that and it's working fine but when RPM is stable. But when RPM change rapidly then it's not working fine.

```
const int kPinRPM = 3;        // RPM / Digital Pin 3
const int RPMInterrupt = 1;   // RPM's interrrupt pin
byte engineCylinders = 2;         // Engine cylinders = 4;
byte engineCycles = 4;            // Engine cycle = 2
int refreshInterval = 750;        // Milliseconds between sensor updates
unsigned long previousMillis = 0;
volatile int RPMpulses = 0;
int RPM, Final_RPM;

const int kPinInj = 12;

volatile uint32_t kInjTime = 0;

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(250000);

  pinMode(kPinRPM, INPUT_PULLUP); // Enable internal pullup
  attachInterrupt(RPMInterrupt, countRPM, FALLING); //Interrupt for RPM

  pinMode(kPinInj, OUTPUT);  
}

void loop()
{
  if(millis() - previousMillis > refreshInterval)
  {
    previousMillis = millis();
    RPM =  getRPM();
  }

  Serial.println(RPM);

  if((kInjTime > 0) && ((millis() - kInjTime) >= 10))
  {
    kInjTime = 0;
    digitalWrite(kPinInj, LOW);
  }
}

void countRPM()
{
  RPMpulses++;

  if(RPMpulses % 2 == 0)           // Skip alternative pulse
  {
    kInjTime = millis();
    digitalWrite(kPinInj, HIGH);
  }
}

int getRPM()
{
  Final_RPM = int(RPMpulses * (60000.0 / float(refreshInterval)) * engineCycles / engineCylinders / 2.0);
  RPMpulses = 0;
  Final_RPM = min(99999, Final_RPM);
}
```

After SUGGESTION, updating my codes. But it output waveform has some problem. In white circle, you can see that problem.

[image: Waveforms]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than saying

```
if(RPMpulses % 2 == 0)           // Skip alternative pulse
  {
    kInjTime = millis();
    digitalWrite(kPinInj, HIGH);
  }
```

and later setting `kPinInj` in the main loop, you could act as follows:

```
digitalWrite(kPinInj, RPMpulses & 1); // Set or clear kPinInj
if(RPMpulses & 1) 
  kInjTime = millis();  // Store alternate times
```

This would ensure that your trace 1 toggles properly.  If you want a shorter up-time on that trace, you could treat `CHANGE` interrupts rather than `FALLING`, and maintain `RPMpulses` as a number twice as big as now, ie use 120000 instead of 60000 in the RPM calculation, and could say:

```
digitalWrite(kPinInj, (RPMpulses & 3)==1); // Set or clear kPinInj
if((RPMpulses & 3)==1) 
  kInjTime = millis();  // Store alternate fall times
```

Note, the floating point arithmetic in `getRPM()` is slow.  At a 750 ms refresh interval, that may not matter much.  But you probably can get good enough results rather more quickly using just integer arithmetic, if you parenthesize the expression somewhat as follows:

```
Final_RPM = ((RPMpulses * (60000UL / 2) * (engineCycles/engineCylinders)) / refreshInterval;
```

That is, do any remainderless divisions early; multiply all the remaining numerator terms together into a large number; then divide by the comparatively small `refreshInterval`, ending up with numerous significant digits without the use of floating point arithmetic, which takes many milliseconds on typical Arduino systems.

*Edit 2:* If your modified code still says `RPMpulses = 0;` within `getRPM()`, you may get a glitch at the end or beginning of each   refresh interval.  You may instead need to say `RPMpulses = 1;`, or `RPMpulses &= 1;`, or some such.  Also, to avoid an extra count when the latter expression is 1 instead of 0, say `RPM0 = RPMpulses &= 1;` and use `(RPMpulses-RPM0)` instead of `RPMpulses` in calculating `Final_RPM`.

Comment: Thank you. I tried out this code. But I faced some problem in Output waveform. I just posted out photo. Please see it.

Comment: @Hasan see edit 2

Comment: Ok, thank you. It is working fine now after your second suggestion. Of course, I do. Don't worry.

Answer (score 1):

There are some things you shouldn't be doing within an interrupt service routine (ISR) like `countRPM()`:

1. Don't call the `millis()` function. It depends on other interrupts which will be disabled during the execution of your ISR.
2. Don't call `digitalWrite` or any other functions
3. Don't use execution cycles hungry operators like `%` (modulo). To obtain modulo 2, just use a bit mask for the LSB.

What you should actually be doing within the ISR is just setting/resetting a flag or variable. Then, do all your stuff in the `loop()` function according the value of the flag or variable.

Comment: Calling `millis()` is OK. It won't increment inside the IRS, but it works fine in an use case like this.

Comment: 1. As E.B. notes, calling `millis()` is ok – it doesn't need interrupts to report a result.   2. Although `digitalWrite()` is slow  – a couple of microseconds – it's ok to call it.  It's true that calling non-reentrant functions should be avoided.  3. Typically, compiler implements div or mod by any power of 2 by shifting or via bitwise AND with a mask; ie, while % may in general be "execution cycle hungry", %2 isn't.  That said, I'd use a mask as you suggest.

Comment: Hey, @jwpat7, I'm also E.B.! :)